# how to return json from groovy please?

Tags: json, groovy

My environment is openjdk version "1.7.0_75", tomcat-7.0.82, groovy-2.4.13, jquery-3.2.1.
Now I want use ajax post some data to groovy, and want groovy return json to ajax.

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    url: "edit.groovy",
    data: json,
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(data) {
        console.log('ok');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log('err');
    }
});
```

And edit.groovy:

```
response.contentType = 'application/json';
out << "{rs: 2}";
```

My question is, why the log is 'err', is my groovy return a right json type please? How to fix it please?

Comment: Look at what data contains. Open your browser dev tools, its network panel, and look at the request and response.

Comment: Thank you, I see that is not json, and I know it, because the log is 'err'. I just do not know what is my wrong. And by tim_yates's answer, I know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"{rs: 2}"
```

Isn't valid json the name had to be in double quotes

```
'{"rs": 2}'
```

Just use a builder with a map, and it will be done for you

```
new JsonBuilder([rs: 2]).toString()
```